# Php paypal integration Classes

Tags: php, paypal

I need a php paypal class to inntegrate PayPal payments to my website.
User from form should be able to order the service, it should redirect to paypal pay page and after the payment is done, i should get back the "success" parameter to mysql database with generated invoice number from paypal.

This class seems to work:
[simple-paypal-integration-in-php](https://github.com/JStockus/php/tree/f9b5b13386301d27a63316a7e13fa1addf935293)

but there is one problem: after user makes payment, i get "success" status in my db table but the invoice number always being generated different than paypal does. And I don't know why is that. May be you know some better classes i could use to make PayPal payments or how to fix that class.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

please use paypal adaptive payment api it is very simple to implements in your projects

Comment: is this the only this one I should use ?